# Nginx doing a proxy_pass to complete URL

Tags: nginx, proxypass, x-accel-redirect

My servlet is sending an X-Accel-Redirect with the complete URL like 
/cached/http://example.com/test/index.html. It has to be complete URL because of our business logic which determine where the resource exist on the web.

And I want nginx to download the content from http://example.com/test/index.html and serve as if it came from the original URL request. Thus I don't want to do a rewrite (or redirect). 
I am trying the below mentioned conf but its not working.

```
location /cached/(.*)$ {
proxy_pass  $1;
}
```

Is there any way to use absolute URL from the match URI and do a proxy_pass to it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show an example of this `/cached` URL ?

Comment: Its already there in the first line of the question "/cached/http://example.com/test/index.html"

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a regular expression match for location

```
location ~ '/cached/(.*)$' {
#       ^^^                         this is for regex
   proxy_pass  $1?$args;
}
```